# Uploading standalone WatchOS app to Apple Store without iOS companion app

Tags: watchos, apple-developer, watchos-10

I'm working on a standalone WatchOS app and I'm wondering if it's possible to upload it to the Apple Store without having an accompanying iOS app. I've seen mixed information in the documentation, and I'm looking for clarification on the submission process for standalone WatchOS applications.

Has anyone successfully submitted a standalone WatchOS app, and if so, what steps are involved in the submission process? Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!